# jquery next and this not working

Tags: jquery, siblings

I am trying to have an input checkbox trigger whether the b version of the question shows up. If they choose never it goes away. I'm using two classes to listen. When .showb is clicked go find the next .bques and show it. When .hidb is clicked, go find the next .bques and hide it. Seems pretty easy but I'm bashing my head as to why it's not working. Please help.

Using **$("p").next(".bques").show("fast");** instead of **$(this).next(".bques").show("fast");** shows all b questions on the page. I've also tried **.nextAll** with no luck. Why isn't **this** working? Is it a child sibling problem?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { background:#def3ca; margin:3px; width:80px; 
display:none; float:left; text-align:center; }.bques{display:none;}
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>$().ready(function() {

$(".showb").click(function () { $(this).next(".bques").show("fast"); });
$(".hidb").click(function () { $(this).next(".bques").hide("fast"); });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><strong>8a.</strong> How frequently do you see someone take a shortcut that could be dangerous for patients (for example, not washing hands long enough, not changing gloves when appropriate, failing to check armbands, forgetting to perform a safety check)? <br />
<input type="radio" name="shortcut" value="1" id="never8"  tabindex="38" class="required hidb" title="Please choose one of these answers." /><label for="never8"> Never</label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="shortcut" value="2" id="once8"  tabindex="39" class="showb" /><label for="once8"> Once a year</label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="shortcut" value="3" id="twice8"   tabindex="40" class="showb" /><label for="twice8"> Twice a year</label>
</p>

<p class="bques"><strong>8b.</strong> Think of the most recent times you've seen this happen. Who have you spoken with about the problem. Check each box that applies: <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="shortcut_cc[]" value="none" id="none8"   tabindex="44" title="Please choose at least one of these answers." /><label for="none8"> Have not spoken with anyone.</label> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="shortcut_cc[]" value="ff"  id="ff8"  tabindex="45" /><label for="ff8"> Have spoken with friends and family.</label> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="shortcut_cc[]" value="coworkers" id="coworkers8" tabindex="46" /><label for="coworkers8"> Have spoken with some of my co-workers.</label> <br />
</p>

<p><strong>9a.</strong>  How frequently do you see a situation where someone might be making a mistake when doing an assessment, doing triage, diagnosing, suggesting treatment/medication options, or performing a procedure? <br />
<input type="radio" name="mistake" value="1" id="never9"   tabindex="51" class="required hidb" title="Please choose one of these answers." /><label for="never9"> Never</label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="mistake" value="2" id="once9"   tabindex="52" class="showb" /><label for="once9"> Once a year</label> <br />
<input type="radio" name="mistake" value="3" id="twice9"   tabindex="53" class="showb" /><label for="twice9"> Twice a year</label> <br />
</p>

<p class="bques">9b. Think of the most recent times you've seen this happen. Who have you spoken with about the problem. Check each box that applies: <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mistake_cc[]" value="none" id="none9"   tabindex="57" title="Please choose at least one of these answers." /><label for="none9"> Have not spoken with anyone.</label> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mistake_cc[]" value="ff"  id="ff9"  tabindex="58" /><label for="ff9"> Have spoken with friends and family.</label> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mistake_cc[]" value="coworkers" id="coworkers9" tabindex="59" /><label for="coworkers9"> Have spoken with some of my co-workers.</label>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
 $().ready(function() {

  $(".showb").click(function () { $(this).parent().next(".bques").show("fast"); });
  $(".hidb").click(function () { $(this).parent().next(".bques").hide("fast"); });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` is working, it's your use of `next` which is incorrect.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> **.next( [ selector ] )**
>
> Get the immediately following sibling
>   of each element in the set of matched
>   elements. If a selector is provided,
>   it retrieves the next sibling only if
>   it matches that selector.

There are no siblings of the `.hidb` radio which match your selector. What you need is the next sibling of the *parent* `<p>` element.

```
$(this).parent().next(".bques").hide("fast");
```

> **.parent( [ selector ] )**
>
> Get the parent of each element in the
>   current set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector.

The first step in debugging a problem like this would usually be

```
alert($(this).next(".bques").length);
```

Which shows you that your selector is not matching any elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a child-sibling problem. The issue is that `.showb` stops once it gets to the end of what's in its parent `p` element. So it will look at follow objects -- some combination of `<label>`, `<br>` and `<input>` until it gets to `</p>`, at which point it stops searching and executes `show()` on nothing.

You want something like

```
$(".showb").click(function () { $(this).parent().next(".bques").show("fast"); });
$(".hidb").click(function () { $(this).parent().next(".bques").hide("fast"); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation.