# Cannot .removeClass using $(this).next() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having a textarea which border is colored as red if it is empty.
I have emoji picker installed on the textarea, which adds a div to hold the picker.

The automatically created div is just right after the textarea and what I am trying to achieve to remove the red border a soon as the user type something.

The script that I have works fine for the textarea itself but does not remove it from the div that holds the emoji picker

**This is what I have**

```
<div class="form-group">

<p class="emoji-picker-container"></p>

<textarea name="title" id="title" class="form-control mandatory" rows="3" placeholder="Type your answer here" data-emojiable="converted" data-emoji-input="unicode" style="height: 100px; display: none;" data-id="e4914124-a85d-4ff4-96d7-9bfd0fd5a1df" data-type="original-input"></textarea>

<div class="emoji-wysiwyg-editor form-control mandatory" data-id="e4914124-a85d-4ff4-96d7-9bfd0fd5a1df" data-type="input" placeholder="Type your answer here" contenteditable="true" style="height: 100px;" spellcheck="false"></div>


</div>
```

**and this is the jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        checkInput();
    })

    $('.mandatory').on('input change',checkInput)

    function checkInput()
    {
        $('.mandatory').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {

                $(this).addClass('invalid');
                
                } else {
                    $(this).next().removeClass("invalid");
                    
                $(this).removeClass('invalid')}
        })
    }
```

I have tried everything I could think of.... `next()`, `prev()`, `nextAll()`...
Also tried to use `$('#emoji-wysiwyg-editor').next()`, which removes it, but if I have more than one textarea with emoji picker, it removes it everywhere

Also, tried searching here and the ideas here also did not work.
[jquery next and this not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142210/jquery-next-and-this-not-working)

One thing that is unique for each textarea and respectively for the created div is the `data-id="e4914124-a85d-4ff4-96d7-9bfd0fd5a1df"` maybe could be used as a selector but, don't know how to approach it.

**This is the emojipicker**
http://onesignal.github.io/emoji-picker/demo/

and this is a **fiddle** showing the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/largan/3d7bkwg9/11/

Comment: could you show a wrking fiddle for your code so that we can re-produce your problem?

Comment: i want to see what output appears in browser when emoji picker is applied so that i can make you a selector to remove your relavent class

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt, the demo is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to use `.val()` on  the div, but it needs to be `.text()`.

You can use `var $val = $(this).val() || $(this).text()`; it will detect if it will be `.val()` or `.text()`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  checkInput();
})

$('.mandatory').on('input change', checkInput)

function checkInput() {
  $('.mandatory').each(function() {
    var $val = $(this).val() || $(this).text()
    if ($val == '') {
      $(this).addClass('invalid');
    } else {
      $(this).next().removeClass("invalid");
      $(this).removeClass('invalid')
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

<p class="lead emoji-picker-container"></p>

<textarea name="title" id="title" class="form-control mandatory" rows="3" placeholder="Type your answer here" data-emojiable="converted" data-emoji-input="unicode" style="height: 100px; display: none;" data-id="e4914124-a85d-4ff4-96d7-9bfd0fd5a1df" data-type="original-input"></textarea>

<div class="emoji-wysiwyg-editor form-control mandatory" data-id="e4914124-a85d-4ff4-96d7-9bfd0fd5a1df" data-type="input" placeholder="Type your answer here" contenteditable="true" style="height: 100px;" spellcheck="false"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that's a nice catch. I didn't notice that I used val. That shoved it. Thanks

Comment: No problem, Happy to help